# Why are there still floats in this item I'm trying to put into DDB after parse_float?

Tags: python, json

I have a dataframe that can have some columns that are numerical values (some are whole, some are not), and I need to get the data into AWS DynamoDB. DynamoDB isn't happy about floats and wants Decimals only.

I am currently doing:

```
results = formatted_df.T.to_dict().values()

with self.approval_table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for result in results:
        formatted_item = json.loads(json.dumps(result), parse_float=Decimal)
        batch.put_item(Item=formatted_item)
```

But with or without the `json.loads(json.dumps(...),...)` on put_item, I'm still getting `Float types are not supported. Use Decimal types instead.` I am not sure why, as I thought this was supposed to handle getting rid of the Float types.

Any help to figure out what I'm missing here would be greatly appreciated